# Regular expressions, extract specific parts of pattern

Tags: r, regex

I haven't worked with regular expressions for quite some time, so I'm not sure if what I want to do can be done "directly" or if I have to work around.

My expressions look like the following two:

```
crb_gdp_g_100000_16_16_ftv_all.txt
crt_r_g_25000_20_40_flin_g_2.txt
```

Only the parts replaced by a asterisk are "varying", the other stuff is constant (or irrelevant, as in the case of the last part (after "f*_"):

```
cr*_*_g_*_*_*_f*_
```

Is there a straightfoward way to get only the values of the asterisk-parts? E.g. in case of "r" or "gdp" I have to include underscores, otherwise I get the r at the beginning of the expression. Including the underscores gives "*r*" or "*gdp*", but I only want "r" or "gdp".

Or in short: I know a lot about my expressions but I only want to extract the varying parts. (How) Can I do that?

Comment: What do you want your final output to look like? A vector of length 2? a list of length 2 with 6 elements in each list item? ....

Comment: `strsplit(gsub("cr(\\w+)_(\\w+)_g_(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)_f(\\w+)_.+", "\\1.\\2.\\3.\\4.\\5.\\6", str), "\\.")` should do

Comment: I only want a list with the * parts. E.g. in case of the first expression I would like a list with the following matches: "b" "gdp" "100000" "16" "16" "tv".

Comment: I'm currently trying what @Cath suggested.

Comment: I modified it a bit to have separate elements

Comment: Perhaps try the `stringr` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html : remplace all your constant expressions by a special character and then split it by this special character.

Comment: @MrSnake, that's where I was starting from. I think what Cath suggested should work. Modifying it a bit shouldn't be a problem. Thanks!

Comment: The answer that has just been deleted might also help (should have thought about that earlier). Thanks to all of you (including @Michael Bird).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub` with captures and then `strsplit` to get a list of the separated elements:

```
str <- c("crb_gdp_g_100000_16_16_ftv_all.txt", "crt_r_g_25000_20_40_flin_g_2.txt")
strsplit(sub("cr([[:alnum:]]+)_([[:alnum:]]+)_g_([[:alnum:]]+)_([[:alnum:]]+)_([[:alnum:]]+)_f([[:alnum:]]+)_.+", "\\1.\\2.\\3.\\4.\\5.\\6", str), "\\.")
#[[1]]
#[1] "b"      "gdp"    "100000" "16"     "16"     "tv"    
#[[2]]
#[1] "t"     "r"     "25000" "20"    "40"    "lin"
```

*Note:* I replaced `\\w` with `[[:alnum:]]` to avoid inclusion of the underscore.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only one question. If I use the following pattern instead of yours, it doesn't work: "cr[b|t]_(gdp|r)_g_[:digit:]+_*" Why?

Comment: @tho_mi to capture the patterns you need to put it between brackets. And when you put things inside square brackets then there is no special character (like the pipe means just the pipe and not "or") and so it just looks for "b" or "|" or "t" for example in your first pattern

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `regmatches` and `regexec` to extract these values like this:

```
regmatches(str, regexec("^cr([^_]+)_([^_]+)_g_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_f([^_]+)_.*$", str))
[[1]]
[1] "crb_gdp_g_100000_16_16_ftv_all.txt" "b"                                 
[3] "gdp"                                "100000"                            
[5] "16"                                 "16"                                
[7] "tv"                                

[[2]]
[1] "crt_r_g_25000_20_40_flin_g_2.txt" "t"                                "r"
[4] "25000"                            "20"                               "40"
[7] "lin"
```

Note that the first element in each vector is the full string, so to drop that, we can use `lapply` and `"["`

```
lapply(regmatches(str, 
                 regexec("^cr([^_]+)_([^_]+)_g_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_f([^_]+)_.*$", str)),
       "[", -1)
[[1]]
[1] "b"      "gdp"    "100000" "16"     "16"     "tv"    

[[2]]
[1] "t"     "r"     "25000" "20"    "40"    "lin"
```